# Integrate via substitution and derivation rule

Tags: integration, trigonometry, derivatives

I have to solve

[this integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28integrate%20%28sqrt%281-%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-r%5E2%29%29%29%20over%20y%20from%20-sqrt%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29%20to%20sqrt%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29%29%20over%20x%20from%20-r%20to%20r)

$$\int_{-r}^{+r}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2-r^2}} \operatorname d y \operatorname d x$$

with substitution and then the trick that $\dfrac 1 {\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \dfrac{\mathsf d\;\arcsin(x)}{\mathsf d\;x\qquad\quad\;\,} $

can someone give me a tip on what I should substitute in order to continue?

Comment: you have to let wolfram alpha calculate again, when the page is loaded or it says it doesn't understand the expression

Comment: You could use polar coordinates.. to attack both nominator and denominator...

Comment: Something is wrong with that integral beaucase the denominator is always $0$. Try switching to polar coordinates and you will see why.

Comment: The original assingnement was to calculate the surface of a half shere (explicitly without polar coordinates) which is given by r(x,y)=(x,y,sqrt(r^2-x^2-y^2))

Answer (score 1):

I would say

$\displaystyle \int_{-r}^{+r}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2-r^2}} \operatorname d y \operatorname d x=4\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}} \operatorname d y \operatorname d x=$

$\displaystyle=4\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\right)^2}} \operatorname d y \operatorname d x=$

$\displaystyle =4r\int_{0}^{r}\left[\arcsin \frac{y}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\right]_{0}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\operatorname dx=\cdots $

Answer (score 0):

First use $x=r \sin(u)$ so, $\mathrm d x = r \cos u\, \mathrm d u$

$$\begin{align}
& \int_{-r}^{+r}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2-r^2}}\; \operatorname d y \operatorname d x
\\
& = \int_{-r}^{+r}\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{+\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{r^2-x^2-y^2}} \;\operatorname d y \operatorname d x
\\
& = \int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}r|r| \cos u \int_{-r \cos u}^{+r\cos u} \sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2\cos^2 u - y^2}} \;\operatorname d y \operatorname d u
\end{align}$$

Now can you see how to use the identity?

Comment: ah i get it but then i get this

\begin{align}
& = \int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2} \int_{-r \cos u}^{+r\cos u} r\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{y}{rcosu}^2}} \;\operatorname d y \operatorname d u
\end{align}

but if i use the identity i get arcsin(1)-arcsin(-1) which is pi. and the i end up with r*pi^2 because i have to integrate r*pi from pi/2 to -pi/2